# Squid proxy: LAN IPs are not hide for remote desktop

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I want to hide our internal LAN IP's(static IPs) behind squid proxy. I have done configuration, now all the traffic are going through squid proxy only. What I assume that after I configure squid no one from outside of our LAN could not able to remote desktop to any local LAN systems, but it is not working as I thought of. I am able to do remote desktop from out side after I configure Proxy server LAN but I shouldn't. what would be the problem, should I do something else with squid? or squid can't do what I want? If not is there any other technology could satisfy my requirement?

My requirement is No one should do remote desktop from outside to our LAN's system. If someone want to do remote desktop to our LAN's system they should be connected over secure connection. we are thinking about LDAP to make secure connection. other then secure connection nothing should be allow.

I hope that am able to explain what I want.

**Additional info:** I am using Mikrotik router(final gateway) for our LAN. Traffic are pass over proxy server which is also connected in our LAN.

Answer (score 1):

"or squid can't do what I want?" Yes, Squid can't do what you want.

You have to block the RDP Port 3389 with your firewall/router.